# How to extract the best parameters from <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object at 0x7f37ccfcdd50>? How to interpret this output?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, gridsearchcv, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to run a GridSearchCV for find the out the best parameter. Parameter provided as

```
params_space = {'c1': [scipy.stats.expon(scale=0.5)],'c2': [scipy.stats.expon(scale=0.05)]}
```

After executing the grid search, when I print the best_params_ following is the output:

```
" " "print("Best Params : ", rs.best_params_,"\n")

Best Params :  {'c1': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object at 0x7f37ccfcdd50>, 'c2': <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object at 0x7f37ccfd8790>} " " "
```

How to extract the value of **C1** and **C2** as I need it for training my model?

Comment: Please [reprex]

Comment: Noted. Shall add the preceding code.